# why can the typescript compiler not tell value is defined when explicitly typed in the same scope

Tags: typescript

I have this code:

```
interface Foo {
  value?: string;
}

const item1: Foo = { value: 'foo' }

// Object is possibly 'undefined'.
console.log(`Message ${item1.value.substring(4)}`);

const item2 = { value: 'foo' }

// all good in the hood
console.log(`Message ${item2.value.substring(4)}`);
```

When `item1` is typed as foo, `tsc` cannot tell whether value is defined or not even though it is declared in the same scope.

I could understand if the item1 was passed into a function but not in the same scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say; you *explicitly* typed that `item1` is of type `Foo`. The property `value` on `Foo` is defined to be of type `string | undefined`, thus Typescript will tell you that `value` might be undefined.

When you don't specify the type of `item2`, Typescript will infer its type as `{ value: string }` -- and thus `value` is not undefined.

Comment: just feels like it should know this from the code it is compiling.  More of a complaint than question maybe :)

Comment: Typescript does know if you let it naturally infer the type. You "overwrite" the inference by specifying the type. I would actually consider it a strength of typescript

Comment: interesting, I totally get it for different scopes but I can't see the benefit here

Comment: Haha I do get what you mean, but can you then see the benefit of declaring `value` to be of optional here?

Comment: I understand now that you are telling the compiler that no matter what, this is the type but I am struggling to see why this beneficial

Comment: there is absolutely no way this value is undefined but the compiler has been instructed otherwise